# Как правильно примонтировать карту памяти в Linux?

Tags: linux, debian

Есть карта памяти, и хочу сделать так, чтобы она всегда монтировалась при запуске системы (Debian).
В /etc/fstab пишу:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/archive vfat auto,user,exec,rw,async 0 0
```

Всё запускается нормально, но если карту памяти вытащить, то операционная система не загрузится, будет выдавать ошибку:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb"
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Если карту памяти вставить обратно, то операционная система запустится успешно.
Как правильно примонтировать эту карту памяти, чтобы операционная система запускалась, даже если никакой карты памяти не стоит?

Comment: `$ man -P cat mount | grep nofail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если через /etc/fstab - можно добавить опцию `nobootwait` тогда строка в fstab будет такой:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/archive vfat nobootwait,auto,user,exec,rw,async 0 0
```

fstab(5):

> Программа mountall (8), которая монтирует файловую систему во время
>   загрузки, также распознает дополнительные параметры, которых нет у
>   обычного инструмента mount (8). Это: bootwait который может быть
>   применен к удаленным файловым системам, установленным вне / usr или /
>   var, без которых mountall (8) не задерживает загрузку для них;
>   nobootwait который может быть применен к не-удаленным файловым
>   системам, чтобы явным образом проинструктировать mountall (8) не
>   задерживать загрузку для них;

Comment: Может быть я что-то не так делаю, но добавление nobootwait никак не повлияло на эту проблему.

Comment: @Riur при добавлении опции вообще ничего не изменилось? ошибка та же? попробуйте добавить еще опцию nofail (не сообщает об ошибках для этого устройства, если оно не существует. Будет пытаться подключить диск, однако процесс загрузки будет продолжаться после того, как mount достигнет таймаута)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Помогло добавление именно nofail, без nobootwait.  
Т.е. сейчас рабочая строка в /etc/fstab выглядит вот так: /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/archive vfat nofail,auto,user,exec,rw,async 0 0